# How to enumerate new column?

Tags: python, django, sqlite

In my Django admin I have a `TabularInLine` class. In the picture, each element of this class is numbered with it's own `ID`. This `TabularInLine` class has a foreign key to an other class (class `Part`). How I can to numerate that for each `FK` with the numbering (`my_id`) started from 1 as in the picture below?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can define your own `insert` operation which does those steps:

- query database with your new entry's foreign key
- get count of results
- assign my_id=count+1

let's say you already have that table in your database.
you want to add a new entry to database, which has `FK="three"`.

- query DB for objects(`FK="three"`).
- count of results is 2. (the last two rows)
- assign my_id=3

Comment: I understand your idea, but don't know how to realise it. How to count amount elements at FK?